# How to update particular array index in mongoDB using a variable

Tags: mongodb

I am creating two collections, one is created transiently and then "stuffed" into another document from the main collection.

I am struggling to understand how I can update  a particular index of an array in a manner similar to below.

```
function stuffDepartmentsIntoLocations() {
    var ops = [];

    db.HR.find().forEach(function(country) 
        {
            for(var i=0;i < country.location.length; i++) {
                db.tempDEPTS.find({"LOCATION_ID":location.LOCATION_ID}).forEach(function(dept)
                    {
                        ops.push(
                            {
                                    "updateOne": 
                                {
                                        "filter": {"_id": country._id },
                                        "update\": {"$push": {"location[i].department":dept}}
                                        }
                                } 
                            );
                        if ( ops.length == 1000 ) {
                                db.HR.bulkWrite(ops,{ "ordered": false });
                                ops = [];
                        }
                    }               
                );          
             }      
      }
    );

   if ( ops.length > 0 ) {
     db.HR.bulkWrite(ops,{ "ordered": false });
   }

 return true;
}"
```

This doesn't seem to be working:

```
"update": {"$push": {"location[i].department":dept}}
```

Error is below:

> { "serverUsed" : "127.0.0.1:27017" , "retval" : true , "ok" : 1.0} {
>   "serverUsed" : "127.0.0.1:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" :
>   "ReferenceError: location is not defined
>   :\nstuffDepartmentsIntoLocations/<@:1:195\nDBQuery.prototype.forEach@src/mongo/shell/query.js:501:1\nstuffDepartmentsIntoLocations@:1:74\n"
>   , "code" : 139 , "codeName" : "JSInterpreterFailure"} [statistics]
>   disconnected

The HR collection document looks like this:

[image]

Department document in the temporary collection I am trying to add is below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ahhhh...just seen it, I used to have a forEach but changed it to an indexed array:

This:

```
db.tempDEPTS.find({"LOCATION_ID":location.LOCATION_ID}).forEach(function(dept)
```

Should be this:

```
db.tempDEPTS.find({"LOCATION_ID":country.location[i].LOCATION_ID}).forEach(function(dept)
```

And now my departments get stuffed into the location documents based on location_id:

[image]

Must be a better way of doing this but seems to work.